# Accessing remote machine process

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to access remote machine but it gives an error. I tried to ping with ip of remote machine to check whether the PC is connected but it works fine.but when i tried tasklist in cmd prompt to access the remote machine it gives "RPC is unavailable".and all the PC's are connected via LAN.

code:

```
connOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
//   connOptions.Authority = "ntlmdomain:domain";
string MyComputerName = sName.ToString();
string machineName = MyComputerName;
connOptions.Username = machineName + "\\" + MyComputerName;
//  connOptions.Username = MyComputerName;
                    connOptions.Password = "";
                    if (MyComputerName.ToUpper() == Environment.MachineName.ToUpper())
                    {
                        // Create the management scope with given credentials
                        myScope = new ManagementScope(@"\ROOT\CIMV2", connOptions);

                    }

                   else { 
                     myScope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + MyComputerName + @"\ROOT\CIMV2",connOptions);
                    myScope.Connect();
                    }


                }
                catch (SocketException ex3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("FormatException caught!!!");
                }
                catch (Exception ex4)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception caught!!!");

                }
```

myScope.Connect(); gives "UNAuthorizedAccessException"

Do i need any settings to be done in web.config file or do i have to do any kind of settings which will get this code into working?

Comment: Hows your security setup?  What account is this code running under? That exception indicates that you have a security problem. Have you looked at the ManagementScope options property to correctly set username and password data. This link will give you more detail:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257337(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @jjay225 Rpc is running on both machines.Grant all permissions in Dcomcnfg.exe.Firewalls disabled. ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get(); throws exception.The link which gave works successfully for local machine but when connected to remote machine throws exception.